# Is there a way to split an array into a multidimensional array with a conditional?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to "Implement a first method size_splitter which takes two parameters: an array, and a integer (the size). We will assume that the array only contains words, e.g. Strings, and that the arbitrary rule is to form two groups: the first one with words of the given size (second parameter of the method), and the other group with all the other words.

The size_splitter method should return an array of two arrays - the two groups defined above - with the contents sorted alphabetically."

I can so far return the size of the array, but any sort of sorting doesnt work right.

I have tried to create 2 empty arrays and all words in the main array that == the target size go into array1 and others into array2. then i push arrays 1 and 2 into the main array.
after that i want to return the arrays both sorted, but i am not quite far enought to worry about that.

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  # TODO: Return an array of two arrays, the first containing
  #       words of length `size`, the second containing all the other words
  #       In addition to this split, each array should be *sorted*
  ary1 = []
  ary2 = []
  array.map do |word|
    word.length == size ? ary1.push(word) : ary2.push(word)
    array.push(ary1, ary2)
    return array.sort!
  end
end
```

I expect to at least be able to first sort the elements by size, but that seems to be where the first problems start.

Comment: Hi Derric-d, you say 'that seems to be where the first problems start' can you clarify what problems exactly? Are you not getting the result you want, and if so, what result do you get? Or do you maybe get an error, if so please share that as well. Right now it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I want the method to take an array and a size (so, length of the word element in the array) and sort the array into two sub arrays by the given size. This is what I can't do with the code I have so far, and my main sticking point. I was testing just trying to sort the main array into two sub arrays with the same condition in irb but to no success. I am on mobile but when I get back home I will share my test spec file so maybe that would help more

Answer (score 4):

I would use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to split the array and that just sort the subarrays:

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  array.partition { |string| string.size == size }.map(&:sort) 
end
```

Comment: okay so i had ended up with this code: 

def size_splitter(array, size)
  
  ary1 = []
  ary2 = []
  array.each do |word|
    word.length == size ? ary1.push(word) : ary2.push(word)
    array = [ary1.sort, ary2.sort]
  end
  return array
end

and it passed all my test but returning 2 arrays even though running it through [try ruby](https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/) it would work.

your code passes.. why is that?

Comment: Did you read the docs of the `partition` method? Why are you surprised that my code passes your test? What is unclear to you?

Comment: i did and im not, im surprised that my code doesnt pass specifically having two arrays. I have fixed that though by returning [ary1.sort, ary2.sort] instead of assigning it to array and returning that, even though it first seemed to pass the test of containing two arrays. Your code is crystal clear and makes sense, its just that what i had seemed suitable outside of my test. it probably has to do with just how i set up the test i think though.

Thanks thought for your help!! very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I see you calling array.sort.   On first glance I would be under the impression that this attempts a sort on the parent array that contains the arrays you are actually interested in sorting.

Perhaps try

```
array.push(ary1.sort, ary2.sort)
    return array
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean and that makes sense, however my main problem is trying to sort the array into two sub arrays in the first place.

Comment: seems like you are doing just that.   split then sort.   it would be nice to know the split sizes before hand then you could sort while moving data to its new place, but it doesnt look like you have that luxury.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sorting the array first might be a relatively simple approach.

I don't think that there's a single correct way to implement this, but here's an alternative that adds the values to a hash's values based on whether they match the size condition or not, and then reads the resulting values.

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  array.sort.each_with_object({true => [], false => []}) do |string, hash| 
    hash[string.size == size] << string
  end.values
end
```

This is also quite readable:

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  [
    array.select{|string| string.size == size}.sort,
    array.reject{|string| string.size == size}.sort
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While I consider @spickermann answer the best approach, I'd suggest a fix for you method.

Move the `return` outside the `map` loop, but use `each` instead, since you defined empty arrays to collect the elements. Then return the two sorted arrays:

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  ary1 = []
  ary2 = []
  array.each do |word|
    word.length == size ? ary1.push(word) : ary2.push(word)
  end
  return [ary1.sort, ary2.sort]
end

ary = %w|Tom Bob Greg Sam Sonny Thomas|

size_splitter(ary, 3)
#=> [["Bob", "Sam", "Tom"], ["Greg", "Sonny", "Thomas"]]
```